# Проблема с аннотацией @Query в Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает параметр encoded = true в описании аннотации @Query?

```
@Query(value = "q", encoded = true) q: String = "Москва")
```

отправляет в запрос перекодированную строку. Попробовал с @MapQuery - такая же ситуация. Неужели, использовать только @Url?

Comment: Вписать незакодированную Москву в любую часть адреса вы не сможете никаким способом - потому что в url-адресах поддерживаются только печатные ASCII-символы и кириллица в их число не входит

Comment: В браузере запрос отрабатывает и с кириллическим параметром - тут идет обработка запроса на уровне сервера или браузера?

Comment: Браузер вам показывает кириллицу, а запрос на сервер точно так же кодирует.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии!